# How do I wire a new fan that I'm replacing

Tags: wiring, fans

**We are replacing old fan with a new fan**

**The wall switches:**

1 switch for the light in the fan

1 switch for the Fan

1 switch for the fireplace which is not used

**The wires that come out of the ceiling are:**

1-Bare wire

2-Green Wire

3-Black Wire

4-Red Wire

5-White Wire

**The New fan has the following Wires:**

1-Blue Wire

2-Black Wire

3-White Wire

4-Green Wire ( This wire is screw into the base of the fan so I assume it's a ground)

**How do I hook up the new Fan?**

**Is the extra wire from the ceiling for the Fire place?**

Comment: Extra wall in the ceiling?  ???  Add pictures please.

Answer (score 1):

The bare wire coming from the ceiling is the grounding conductor, and should be connected as described in the manufacturers installation instructions that came with the fan.

The green wire is also a grounding conductor, and should be connected in a similar fashion as the bare wire.

The white wire is the grounded (neutral) conductor, and should be connected to the white wire on the fan using a twist-on wire connector (or other approved means).

The black wire is a switched ungrounded (hot) conductor, and will be energized when one of the switches is closed (on).  This should be connected to either the black (fan) or blue (lights) wire on the fan, depending on which function you want this switch to control.

The red wire is a switched ungrounded (hot) conductor, and will be energized when one of the switches is closed (on).  This should be connected to either the black (fan) or blue (lights) wire on the fan, depending on which function you want this switch to control.

***WARNING:*** Since I'm not there, I can't be 100% sure this answer is correct. I'm basing this on common installations, but there are no guarantees this is wired in a common way.

One foolproof method, is to connect the new fan exactly as the old fan was connected.

Answer (score 0):

With that many red and black wires at the fan box you could have travelers for a 3 way in that box. If the switch is a 3 way and you cannot duplicate all of the original connections have an electrican wire it for you.